# Choosing a V-Drum

Tags: drums, drum-kits

I am beginner drummer and I need to buy a V-drum. What makes a good v-drum?  What should I look for to avoid buying a bad v-drum?

Comment: By V-Drum, do you mean an item from Roland's line of electronic drums which they have a registered trademark for the name *V-Drums*? Or do you mean an electronic drum kit in general? Are you looking for a full kit for practice like kick, snare hats, etc? Or are you looking for more like an electronic practice pad or electronic hand drums? Why do you want electronic drums? If you are trying to practice quietly, I'd recommend mesh heads on an acoustic set instead of electronic drums.

Comment: Eletronic drum kit in general and full kit to practice everything.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Why mesh head instead of electronic drums?

Comment: Because you will better learn how to play real drums and you won't be spending huge amounts on a decent electronic kit. Instead you can spend that money on better acoustic pieces. If you go the mesh heads route, then there are also special cymbals that are very quiet (I know Zildjian makes some). Electronics kits are either not at all like playing drums or extremely expensive ($2000+).

Answer (score 1):

Electronic Kits have pros and cons, as with acoustic kits. The main thing you want to look for in buying a good E-Kit is when you sit down and start to play, that you are comfortable and it feels right. Usually the heads on a generic entry level E-kit, do not feel the same as an acoustic kit and far away from the actual feel, so you want to look for whether it makes you happy, sit down and have a little jam on it. Chuck some headphones in and just go crazy. if you feel happy after then it usually is going to be good for you. You should avoid low end E-kits, the more expensive electronic kits are usually the best bet for good quality hardware, electronics and just all round better to have, less repairs, less hassle. I'd recommend the **Yamaha** line of E-Kits, they are reliable. Ive been playing for about 10 years and I started on a Yamaha Electronic Kit and stayed on it for about the first 3 years of my drumming.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to mention that electronic drum kits are not 100% silent. They're far more silent that an acoustic kit, but there may still be the noise of the drum sticks on the rubber and mesh pads.

Comment: Playing an instrument that is based on sound vibrations will never be silent. Not even Air Drums are completely silent. There is always some kind of contact which produces vibration, therefore some level of sound as well.